# Asynchronous listening/iteration of pipes in python

Tags: python, multithreading, pipe

I'm crunching a tremendous amount of data and since I have a 12 core server at my disposal, I've decided to split the work by using the multiprocessing library.  The way I'm trying to do this is by having a single parent process that dishes out work evenly to multiple worker processes, then another that acts as a collector/funnel of all the completed work to be moderately processed for final output.  Having done something similar to this before, I'm using Pipes because they are crazy fast in contrast to managed ques.

Sending data out to the workers using the pipes is working fine.  However, I'm stuck on efficiently collecting the data from the workers.  In theory, the work being handed out will be processed at the same pace and they will all get done at the same time.  In practice, this never happens.  So, I need to be able to iterate over each pipe to do something, but if there's nothing there, I need it to move on to the next pipe and check if anything is available for processing.  As mentioned, it's on a 12 core machine, so I'll have 10 workers funneling down to one collection process.

The workers use the following to read from their pipe (called WorkerRadio)

```
for Message in iter(WorkerRadio.recv, 'QUIT'):
    Crunch Numbers & perform tasks here...
    CollectorRadio.send(WorkData)

WorkerRadio.send('Quitting')
```

So, they sit there looking at the pipe until something comes in.  As soon as they get something they start doing their thing.  Then fire it off to the data collection process.  If they get a quit command, they acknowledge and shut down peacefully.

As for the collector, I was hoping to do something similar but instead of just 1 pipe (radio) there would be 10 of them.  The collector needs to check all 10, and do something with the data that comes in.  My first try was doing something like the workers...

```
i=0
for Message in iter(CollectorRadio[i].recv, 'QUIT'):
    Crunch Numbers & perform tasks here...

    if i < NumOfRadios:
        i += 1
    else:
        i = 0

CollectorRadio.send('Quitting')
```

That didn't cut it & I tried a couple other ways of manipulating without success too. I either end up with syntax errors, or like the above, I get stuck on the first radio because it never changes for some reason.  I looked into having all the workers talking into a single pipe, but the [Python site](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) explicit states that "data in a pipe may become corrupted if two processes (or threads) try to read from or write to the same end of the pipe at the same time."

As I mentioned, I'm also worried about some processes going slower than the others and holding up progress.  If at all possible, I would like something that doesn't wait around for data to show up (ie. check and move on if nothing's there).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I've seen some use of managed ques that might allow this to work; but, from my testing, managed ques are *significantly* slower than pipes and I can use as much performance on this as I can muster.

**SOLUTION:**
Based on pajton's post here's what I did to make it work...

```
#create list of pipes(labeled as  radios)
TheRadioList = [CollectorRadio[i] for i in range(NumberOfRadios)]

while True:
    #check for data on the pipes/radios
    TheTransmission, Junk1, Junk2 = select.select(TheRadioList, [], [])
    #find out who sent the data (which pipe/radio)
    for TheSender in TheTransmission:
        #read the data from the pipe
        TheMessage = TheSender.recv()
        crunch numbers & perform tasks here...
```

Comment: Did have look ``IPython.Parallel`` (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_intro.html), it has much more features than multiprocessing, especially regarding asynchronous communictations

Comment: I did not see this before, but I will definitively look into this.  Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using standard system pipes, then you can use [select](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) system call to query for which descriptors the data is available. Bt default `select` will block until at least one of passed descriptors is ready:

```
read_pipes = [pipe_fd0, pipe_fd1, ... ]

while True:
    read_fds, write_fds, exc_fds =  select.select(read_pipes, [], [] )
    for read_fd in read_fds:
        # read from read_fd pipe descriptor
```